# The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a MagicMock

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am writing a unittest for a flask app route that uses a class method. I imported the class into the flask app route file. i wrote the unittest code below and am getting error `The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a MagicMock`. I don't understand why this is failing. My code situation is as follows:

page/flaskApp.py

```
from myapp import MyClass
@app.route('/check')
def checking():
    result = MyClass.check.make.single()
    return result
```

testing.py

```
#patching Myclass and it methods

@patch("page.flaskApp.MyClass", )
def test_check(self, mock_class):
    mock_class.check.make.single.return_value = b'validated'
       
    with app.test_client() as client:       
        response = service.get("/check")
        assert response.content == 'validated'
```

Comment: The error is saying your `view` method is returning a mock.  Which makes sense since it’s a mock object and you didn’t tell it what to return for its `view` other than another mock.